# Action Script 3 load image from mysql using base64 decode, image loaded broken

Tags: php, mysql, image, actionscript-3, base64

I got a little problem. I'm trying to write a code for saving encoded jpeg image in to my MySQL DB. After i load the image back in my as3 app, the image doesn't show properly, it seems like the loader loads just a few of the bytearray's data. Any ideas why this is happening ? Thanks so much. Sorry for bad english ....

```
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder();
var ba1:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData1);
var encoded1:String = Base64.encodeByteArray(ba1);

sendtoserver.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sendData);
    function sendData(evt:Event){
var myData:URLRequest = new URLRequest("xxxx/images.php");
myData.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.obrazek1 = encoded1;
myData.data = variables;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.load(myData);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
function completeHandler(event:Event):void{
         var dekodovani1:String = loader.data.obrazek1;
         var decoded1:ByteArray = Base64.decodeToByteArray(dekodovani1);
         var loaderbyte:Loader = new Loader();
         loaderbyte.loadBytes(decoded1);
         addChild(loaderbyte); 
}
}
```

the image - http://s8.postimg.org/i6j3rvwqd/Untitled_3.jpg
but its must be all over the stage and show correctly, if i decode without using mysql, it show correctly, in the mysql i use blob table

Answer (score 0):

You must change your URLLoaderDataFormat to Text.